# Multiple AWS accounts with multiple dynamoDB URLs and different configurations with spring boot 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, amazon-dynamodb

I have a spring boot project with an amazonDynamoDB connection. Still, I need to query another table in another AWS account with different credentials and a different amazonDynamoDBEndpoint and table name.

So far, this is my configuration file.

```
@Configuration
@EnableDynamoDBRepositories(dynamoDBMapperConfigRef = "dynamoDBMapperConfig", basePackages = "com.myapp.api.dynamodb.repository")
public class DynamoDBConfig {
    @Value("${dynamodb.endpoint}")
    private String dynamoDBEndpoint;
    @Value("${aws.accesskey}")
    private String awsAccessKey;
    @Value("${aws.secretkey}")
    private String awsSecretKey;
    @Value("${aws.table}")
    private String awsTableName;
    @Value("${aws.region}")
    private String awsRegion;

@Bean
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB(AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider) {
        return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(
                        new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(amazonDynamoDBEndpoint, awsRegion))
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(amazonAWSAccessKey, amazonAWSSecretKey)))
                .build();
    }
@Bean
    public DynamoDBMapperConfig dynamoDBMapperConfig(DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride tableNameOverrider) {
        DynamoDBMapperConfig.Builder builder = new DynamoDBMapperConfig.Builder();
        builder.withTypeConverterFactory(DynamoDBTypeConverterFactory.standard());
        builder.withTableNameResolver(DynamoDBMapperConfig.DefaultTableNameResolver.INSTANCE);
        builder.withTableNameOverride(tableNameOverrider());
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride tableNameOverrider() {
        return DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride.withTableNameReplacement(awsTableName);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying is to create a new @Bean for another amazonDynamoDB but I don't know how to configure the new dynamoDB account connection.

Is this even possible? I mean I am creating a new configuration file with the new amazonDynamoDB but I'm getting the error:
`The bean 'dynamoDB-DynamoDBMapper' could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined and overriding is disabled.`

So I tried to name the beans for get two different clients:

```
@Bean("firstClient")
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB(AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider) {
        return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(
                        new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(dynamoDBEndpoint, awsRegion))
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey)))
                .build();
    }

@Bean("secondClient")
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB(AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider) {
        return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(
                        new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(anotherAmazonDynamoDBEndpoint, anotherAwsRegion))
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(anotherAmazonAWSAccessKey, anotherAmazonAWSSecretKey)))
                .build();
    }
```

But I get this error:

```
Description:

Field customDynamoRepository in com.myapp.api.someService required a bean named 'amazonDynamoDB' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'amazonDynamoDB' in your configuration.
```

So I'm totally lost with this problem.
I hope anyone can help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You interact with the DynamoDB service, or any AWS service, through a `client`. When you create that client in code, you supply it with the AWS region and a set of AWS credentials. You don't need to supply endpoints typically. So, for your code to access tables from multiple AWS accounts you either need multiple clients, each with an account-specific set of AWS credentials, or you need a single client where the associated AWS credentials are valid for both accounts and all relevant DynamoDB tables.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer. Can you please elaborate on a code example?
As I said before, I tried to create another client in a different config file, but spring boot asked me to override the bean with this annotation:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

By the way, I'm using the spring-data-dynamodb package from this repository: io.github.boostchicken

Comment: I don't use Spring Boot or Beans but your proposal has two methods with the same signature: `AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB(AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider)` which seems problematic. Also, once you've applied the @Bean annotations, I'm assuming that whatever else refers to a Bean named `amazonDynamoDB` will no longer resolve (because you no longer have a Bean with that name).